# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - pdf2htmlEX

Tags: python, c, pdf

https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX

If I try something like this:

`pdf2htmlEX /path/to/foobar.pdf` in Ubuntu terminal and I have this output:

```
root@user-R520-R522-R620: pdf2htmlEX /home/user/work/a.pdf
Preprocessing: 8/8
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Well, this seems to be a bug. You'd have to debug it. Not quite sure what this is, since it's tagged as both python and C. For the latter one, I'd start by making sure the binary is not stripped and then run it in gdb.

Comment: If the binary *is* stripped (find out by doing `file pdf2htmlEX`) then `strace` might give some clues.

Comment: My own experience with that kind of program (the opposite actually html -> pdf) shows that, unfortunately, they may not test conditions or handle exceptions well and, simply, crash. For instance, that could be 1. no abs path allowed 2. no write access to existing file/directory 3. the pdf is not the correct version 4. unicode in it 5. needs *root* to work nice etc etc.... just suggestions of what is usually tested in programs, but many of the recent free stuff does not. Try a debug mode, or add some `printf` in the code to see where it crashes and why.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I haven't looked at your source but I can suggest you to debug your code with generated core dump.

to generate core dump give command

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

then run your program, it will crash and generate the dump in **core** named file.

give command

```
gdb <your_executable> core
```

give **bt** command in gdb prompt.
It will give backtrace before coredump and you can follow it to get to the root cause...

hope this helps....